# Is it possible for a user to be banned from a private beta?

Tags: discussion

I can't access a private beta that I was committed to (Digital Preservation) anymore... Are all my questions gone from it?

Comment: Can't access it? Any particular messages?

Comment: I just get redirected to the Area51 site (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39787/digital-preservation )...

Answer (score 5):

Per a message at the Digital Preservation meta site for the last week(? ish), the plug on this was going to be pulled on March 18th (today).

IOW, you haven't been banned; the site no longer exists.